# Simple messaging application...getting errno 14: bad address

Tags: c, sockets, errno

I am writing a simple messaging application in C using sockets. When I use function `recvfrom`, it returns `-1` and sets `errno = 14` which is `Bad address` (which I am printing at the end).

The strange thing is that it still reads from the socket and gets the correct message. That is, the application is working perfectly and as expected except for that error.

My question is this: Why do you think I am getting this error? I cannot think of any reason. I was using `inet_pton` to set `peer->sin_addr` but I was getting the same error.

```
// socket file descriptor to send data through
int recv_sock_fd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);

// fill in the peer's address, loopback in this case
struct sockaddr_in *peer = malloc(sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
peer->sin_family = AF_INET;
peer->sin_port   = htons(11110);
char *new = &(peer->sin_addr);
new[0] = 127;
new[1] = 0;
new[2] = 0;
new[3] = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    peer->sin_zero[i] = NULL;
}

bind(recv_sock_fd, peer, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)); 

// check to see if the socket has any data...code removed

char buff[32] = {0};
errno = 0;
int bytes_received = recvfrom(recv_sock_fd, buff, sizeof(buff), NULL, (struct sockaddr *)peer, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));

printf("Bytes recieved: %d: %d : %s\n", bytes_received, errno, strerror(errno));
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look at the signature of [`recvfrom(2)`](http://kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/recv.2.html):

```
ssize_t recvfrom(int sockfd, void *buf, size_t len, int flags,
                 struct sockaddr *src_addr, socklen_t *addrlen);
```

Last argument is an *address*, while you are giving it a plain integer.

Then you're building of the IP address is wrong. Do use [`inet_pton(3)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/inet_pton.3.html), that's what it's for. Also check the return value of the [`bind(2)`](http://kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/bind.2.html), it's surely failing now.

Comment: Correct - and it's an input/output parameter, so you should initialise `socklen_t slen = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);` and pass `&slen`.

Comment: Don't worry, we've all been there :)